# Physical quantities conversion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

searching for experimental values of the consumption rate of $O_2$ by tumor cells I found an article that measures the rate in the units of measure

$$\frac{mol}{cell\cdot s}.$$

The actual measurement was

$$5.5\cdot 10^{-15}\frac{mol}{cell\cdot s},$$

I precise to convert the expression in terms of $kg,\;cm,\;s$ units, but I'm not sure of how to do that. When I tried the result where far away from the order of values that I was expecting. So, I appreciate any help.

Comment: What is $cell$? Like what are the units / what is the size of it?

Comment: @SuperCiocia I'm guessing it's a number? As in "per cell" or "per person"?

Comment: Oxygen has a molar mass of 32 g, and there are 1000 g in a kg.  Your answer should end up being g/cell-s or kg/cell-s, but chemists would normally go with g/cell-s.  By the way, why would you want to convert to something besides mole/cell-s?

Comment: @Philip yeah but you need to give that in units of cm.

Comment: If you'd like a reference book for something like this, Sanjoy Mahajan's great book *The Art of Insight in Science and Engineeting* discusses this in its first chapter. The book's available freely online [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-011-the-art-of-insight-in-science-and-engineering-mastering-complexity-fall-2014/online-textbook/MITRES_6-011F14_art_insfin.pdf).

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. @SuperCiocia, by "cell" is as Philip say: "per cell". So, I guess I can use the volume of a cell to convert the unity to $cm^3$.

Comment: @David White, I need the conversion because I'm working with a mathematical model where the nutrient consumption is only one term in one equation, and all the measures to be in the same physical units in order to remove the variables dimensions..

Comment: I read the book @Philip (the part with the matter of interest), it was very good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the *old* units in terms of the *new* units.

- 1 mole of $0_2$ is an Avogradro's number ($N_A = 6.02214076 \times 10^{23}$) of particles. Each particle here is an $O_2$ molecule, so the mass of a single particle is $m_{O_2} = 2\times m_0$ (technically minus the binding energy, but it's small so let's ignore it). $m_0$ is the number of nucleons in an oxygen atom (neglecting the electrons since their mass contribution is so small) times by the mass of a nucleon. So $m_0 = 16\times u$ (for $^{16}O$) where $u$ is the [atomic mass unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_mass) $1.66 \times 10^{-27}$ kg.
   
  Putting all together:
  $$ 1\,\mathrm{mol} = N_A\cdot m_{0_2} = N_A\cdot 2\cdot m_0 = N_A \cdot 2 \cdot 16 \cdot u \approx 0.032 \,\mathrm{kg}. $$
- Whatever the dimension of a cell is, let's say it's $1 \, \mathrm{cell} = \alpha\, \mathrm{cm}$, where $\alpha$ is the dimension of the cell in centrimetres.

So, all together:
$$ 5.5\cdot 10^{-15}\frac{\mathrm{mol}}{\mathrm{cell}\cdot \mathrm{s}} \Rightarrow  5.5\cdot 10^{-15}\frac{0.032 \,\mathrm{kg}}{\alpha\, \mathrm{cm}\cdot \mathrm{s}} = \frac{1.76\cdot 10^{-16}}{\alpha}\frac{\mathrm{kg}}{\mathrm{cm}\cdot \mathrm{s}}.$$

Comment: @Fernando I am so sorry, $87$ is something i had in my head from something else. For oxygen, it should be $16$ (twice the $Z$ number) unless you are dealing with isotopes. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking a lot and always appear to be 16, then I decided to ask, jajajaja